# Npm as a build tool: how to make my angular2 app build better

Tags: angular, npm

Recently I started to play with angular 2 tutorial and was confused by project structure, so I decided to craft something more convenient to myself. But as I am new to npm, I would like to get some advices and suggestions.

Here is a structure of my project:

```
node_modules
package.json
other_conf_files
src
  app (typescript + typescript html templates)
  static
    assets
      img
      css
    index.html
    systemjs.config.js (put it here as exception to get in the root of dist)
```

Here is a scripts section of package.json for my current project:

```
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist",

    "codecheck": "tslint -c tslint.json --force src/app/**/*.ts",

    "build:ts":"tsc --outDir dist --rootDir src",
    "build:ts:w": "tsc --outDir dist --rootDir src -w",

    "build:resources": "cpx src/static/**/* dist && cpx src/app/**/*.{html,css} dist/app",
    "build:resources:w": "onchange src/static src/app/**/*.{html,css} -- npm run build:resources",

    "prebuild": "npm run clean && npm run codecheck",
    "build": "npm run build:resources && npm run build:ts", 

    "server": "lite-server",
    "start": "npm run build && concurrently \"npm run build:ts:w\" \"npm run build:resources:w\" \"npm run server\" ",

    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  }
```

Lite server serves from ./dist and ./node_modules. Here is an outcome of the 'npm start':

```
dist
  app
  assets
    css
    img
  index.html
  systemjs.config.js
```

What would you change in my scripts and why? Is anything wrong or awful here?
P.s. I don't consider switching to gulp\grunt.

Upd. links to the related blogposts

- [one](https://medium.com/@dabit3/introduction-to-using-npm-as-a-build-tool-b41076f488b0#.mk2at8teg)
- [two](https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-to-npm-as-a-build-tool/)
- [three](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/)

Comment: The question is opinion-based and cannot get a quality answer. You end up with a bunch of temporary files that are inevitable with 'npm as a build tool'. If it works for you now, that's fine. If you're new to this workflow, you will possibly realize its limitations later, Gulp and Webpack are there for a reason.

Comment: I tend to agree, I tried gulp and concept of pipes looks very promising but there were articles about using npm as a build tool, so I decided to give it a try. I will look at the Webpack soon. In the question I just would like to know if I am doing something completely wrong considering the npm as a build tool approach.

Comment: Been there. Ended with Gulp+Webpack. NPM+Webpack may work, but it depends on tasks. Gulp and Webpack are the right tools for for flexibility and speed. It looks ok currently. But tends to grow with time, NPM scripts become too long and WET when new needs appear (besides the fact that it is hard to keep them cross-platform). 'NPM as a build tool' is fine as a concept and religious life stance but has its limitations for real-world tasks, it is just not worth the risk of migration to a new workflow in the middle of the project.